# Regular Information pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am in my first few days of Regular Expression learning. I am trying to do a  simple pattern match to find an occurrence of @@@XXX@@@ markers in my log file where XXX is an uppercase word with no spaces/numeric values allowed there (underscore allowed too). There can be no or multiple spaces between starting &&& and the actual word or the word and the terminating&&&. XXX is always Upper case and no spaces/numeric values allowed there (underscore is allowed).

Some allowed examples:
@@@CAT@@@

@@@    CAT@@@

@@@   CAT   @@@

@@@ CAT_DOG   @@@

I tried doing something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\@{3}(\\s* \\w \\s*)\\@{3}");
```

Doesn't it mean check for 3 instances of @ followed by o to n instances of space followed by a  word followed again by o to n instances of space followed by 3 instances of @ ? 
It captures the cases with @@ but does not capture where more than 3 @ are used.
How do I specify there are 3 and only 3 instances of @? ....And obviously I still have not plugged the uppercase restriction.

Comment: Your examples contain spaces! And there may be some typo, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"(^|[^@])@{3}\s*[_A-Z]+\s*@{3}($|[^@])"
```

Comment: Close, but is missing the allowed spaces between the `@` characters and the letters/underscores. Add some `\s*` in there.

Comment: will this not capture @@@@ CAT @@@@ ?. I want to skip more than 3 instances of @

Comment: @phewataal Then you must specify some separators around the regex. Maybe spaces?

Comment: That's not the regex I wrote. A misplaced comment, I think?

Comment: Thanks much. To help me learn more on this topic, conversely if I were to do file validation and throw error if it finds any markers not matching 3 @@@ requirements, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?:[^@]|^)@{3}(\s*[A-Z_]+\s*)@{3}(?!@)

// or with Java escaping

(?:[^@]|^)@{3}(\\s*[A-Z_]+\\s*)@{3}(?!@)
```

Putting a literal space makes a required space.  So `a b` is different than `ab`.  In your original pattern you had a space between the `\\s+ \w`.  Also `\w` matches lower-case and upper-case alike.  Using a character class will make only upper case match.

---

If you want to avoid more than three (as one of the comments suggests) you have to add a little extra code.

At the start we put this, which says either match a non-@ character, or the start of the string `^`.  The `(?:)` means we don't care about this part of the match.

```
(?:[^@]|^)
```

At the end we have to say the following character cannot be a @.  `(?!)` means fail if the pattern *could* match.  It doesn't end up capturing it, because this is a **zero-width** lookahead.

```
(?!@)
```

I updated the patterns at the top.

These new patterns will **not** match these.

> @@@ CAT_DOG @@@@
>
> @@@@ CAT_DOG @@@

Comment: I added some extra info, and updated the needles to exclude more than three @s.

Comment: Never heard of rubular before, but [here's one](http://rubular.com/r/uV4sY0ydma).

Comment: Thanks.This is working. Sorry for piggybacking another question on this topic. If I were to use this pattern for any other marker, say '*' as my marker instead of @, how would I replace @ with *?

Comment: Replace all the @s with `\*`.  (Escaped because * is a special character.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do.

```
[^@]?@{3}\s*([A-Z_]*)\s*@{3}[^@]
```

1. [^@]? matches any single character other than `@` optionally ( to exclude matching `@@@@` )
2. `@{3}` matches exactly 3 `@` characters
3. `\s*` matches ZERO or MORE whitespace characters
4. [A-Z_]* matches ZERO or MORE upper case letters or `_` characters ).
    The `()` that wrap the expression [capture the contents in a Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) so you
    can [extract the contents easily](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).
5. `\s*` matches ZERO or MORE whitespace characters
6. `@{3}` matches exactly 3 `@` characters
7. [^@] matches any single character other than `@` ( to exclude matching `@@@@` )

Here is an [interactive regular expressions page](http://rubular.com) ( [with your example worked out](http://rubular.com/r/MS1yyo4Y1E) ) that I use all the time to work things like this out.

Comment: I probably did not explain correctly. I don't want:@@@@ CAT @@@@ to be captured. There has to be only 3 instances of @ for the result to appear

Comment: my answer only captures the upper case letter and _ characters in between the `@` signs, see the rublar workpage I linked to.

Comment: In my case, I only want to capture CAT if and onlyif  @@@ CAT @@@ is the input string. It should not capture cat for  @@ CAT @@ or    @@@@ CAT @@@@

Comment: I looked at the Rubular page ( BTW Thanks for showing me that linky. It sure is handy). Please try @@@@CAT@@@@ ( with 4 @'s)

Comment: that is what my answer does, look at the **NEW** [rublar page I created for you](http://rubular.com/r/MS1yyo4Y1E)? I added add `@@CAT@@` and `@@@@ CAT @@@@` at the bottom of the input and see it won't match anything.